# Selenium 2 and Firefox: Session not found exception

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

When I try to run my tests using Firefox 19, Selenium returns an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:188)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
>       at systemTests.LoginPageTest.openPage(LoginPageTest.java:25)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       ...

It works fine when I use Chrome.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It was working until a week ago.

Selenium version: 2.31.0

Firefox version: 19.0.2

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of webdriver

Comment: +1 for the above, especially as "it worked a week ago" suggests Firefox auto-updated and is now out of sync with your Selenium version. v2.31 is the Selenium version you need to be using for FF 19 'support'.

Comment: I'm using selenium 2.31.0

Comment: Adding the selenium-remote-driver jar to the classpath fixed it for me.